# What is cross-timestamp?

Tags: linux, time

My linux system is using linuxptp for network time-sync. I am doing research to see if my system clock can be disciplined to the accuracy at nanosecond level. I ran into this document talking about "cross timestamp" and I don't quite understand what it does and if it can help sync my system clock to the accuracy of nano-second level.
https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/654619/
I'd appreciate your insights

Answer (score 0):

The cross timestamps contain the realtime and monotonic clock
times. The realtime value is needed to discipline that clock using PTP
and the monotonic raw value is used for applications that don't
require a "real" time, but need an unadjusted clock time.